Counterfeit Coins II (green book)
There are 5 bags with 100 coins in each bag. A coin can weigh 9g, 10g, or 11g. Each bag contains coins of equal weight, but we do not know what type of coin each bag contains. You have a digital scale that tells the exact weight. How can you determine the coin types for each bag in only one weighing?
Solution Answer
The problem solution utilizes the pigeonhole principle. In the case of one bag, we need only weigh one coin.
But in the case of 2 bags, there are 3^2 possible combinations of coins types between the bags (pigeons). If we use only 1 coin from bag 2, then we have 3 possible weighings (holes): 18, 19, or 20. This guarantees a collision/ambiguous information from the weighing.
Thus we need to find a suitable number of coins from bag 2 that creates enough "holes" to, at the very least, not guarantee a collision. Then, we can find a pattern to determine the number of coins needed from the remaining bags.
Question
I definitely understand the reasoning/solution approach; but the solution seems to find the # of coins needed from each bag rather quickly. It says that, clearly, we need 3 coins from bag 2 to guarantee a range of 8 possible weighings. Likewise, it says we need 9 coins from bag 3 to guarantee a range of 27 possible weighings, enough to cover 3^3 pigeons.
Is there some trick I'm missing? How do we know that if we take 9 coins from bag 3, 3 coins from bag 2, and 1 coin from bag 1, that we will certainly cover a range of 27 possible weighings? Does this need to be shown through brute force?

3 options per bag, so we should think of the three possible bag weights as a digit of a number in base 3.  Then the first place is the 1s, the second place is the 3s, the third place is the 9s.  If there were a fourth bag, the fourth place (i.e., number of coins to draw) is $3^3 = 27$s.

If you imagine subtracting $9$ grams from each coin, which you can add back in at the end, all coins weigh $0, 1,$ or $2$ grams.  The $1$ coin from bag $1$ can then weigh $0,1,2$ grams.  If we take $3$ coins from bag $2$ they weigh $0, 3,$ or $6$ grams and we have large enough holes that the variation from bag $1$ will not confuse us.  Then $1$ coin from bag $1$ and $3$ coins from bag $2$ weigh a maximum of $8$ grams, so if we take $9$ coins from bag $3$ we won't be confused.  When we weigh $1+3+9$ coins like this we can express the weight in base $3$ and read off the weight of each bag-if we get $23=212_3$ grams we know bag $3$ has coins of $2+9=11$ grams, bag $2$ has coins of $1+9=10$ grams and bag $1$ has coins of $2+9=11$ grams.  To continue the pattern we take $27$ coins from bag $4$ and $81$ from bag $5$.
